# `rm` a file named '--help'?

Tags: unix, command-line, escaping

How does one use `rm` to delete a file named '--help'? When I try, it just shows the help prompt.

I ended up opening a file browser to delete it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two approaches:

```
rm ./--help
rm -- --help
```

This latter approach is supported by many common UNIX tools (`--` means "end of options" by convention, ie. that everything else will be a positional parameter), and is particularly handy in a script, when you don't know what data you'll be dealing with.

Comment: The `./--help` variant is viable on very old Unixen lacking the `--` addition.

Answer (score 3):

The `rm` command will accept '--' to tell it not to process any more options.

```
rm -- '--help'
```

Comment: No quotes are required in this particular example.